# Flutter - How to get the value of a provider call function that requires 'await' within a variable?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider, sqflite, flutter-listview

I'm trying to make a budget app where each budget has its own spending history. Each of those spending histories would have a variable called 'budgetName' which I can compile and total the amount of spending by using sqflite code as below.

```
return await db.rawQuery("select sum(budgetSpent) as total from spending where budgetName ='" + budgetTitle + "'");
```

and this works if I try to use a `.then((value) {print(value);})` when calling the sqflite function and see the value of each budget's spendings in the debug console.

But the problem is that I need the 'budgetTitle' when calling the function so it can compare with the spending's 'budgetName' to get the total spending amount.

So what I have right now is I try to get the spending amount like below:

```
child: BudgetCard(
  budgetName: budget.budgetName,
  budgetSpent: '${Provider.of<SpendingDatabaseHelper>(context, listen: false).getSpecificSpending(budget.budgetName}',
  maxBudget: currency.format(int.parse(budget.maxBudget)),
  svgIcon: iconListBudgetCards[budget.iconValue],
  color: colorSwatch[budget.colorValue],
  percentage: 0.5),
),
```

But it only returns `Instance of 'Future<dynamic>'` because it needs the 'await' before getting the value. But I couldn't find another way of doing this because it needs the 'budgetTitle' to be passed on.

Any help, ideas, or suggestions are highly appreciated! thank you in advance.

Here is the database code:

```
String? budgetSpendingAmount;

getSpecificSpending(budgetTitle) async {
    dynamic result =
        await SpendingDatabaseHelper.instance.getSpendingAmount(budgetTitle);
    String a = result.toString();
    debugPrint('A: $a');
    if (a == '[{total: null}]') {
      a = currency.format(int.parse('000'.trim()));
      budgetSpendingAmount = a;
      print(budgetSpendingAmount);
    } else {
      String? b = a.replaceAll(RegExp(r'[{\}\[\]\-]+'), '');
      String c = b.substring(b.indexOf(":") + 1);
      budgetSpendingAmount = currency.format(int.parse(c.trim()));
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future getSpendingAmount(String budgetTitle) async {
    Database db = await instance.database;
    return await db.rawQuery("select sum(budgetSpent) as total from spending where ='" + budgetTitle + "'");
  }
```

Here is the full code of where I call the function to get the spending amount data:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<List<Budget>>(
      future: Provider.of<BudgetDatabaseHelper>(context).getBudgets(),

      /// Displaying the data from the list
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return const Center();
        }
        return snapshot.data!.isEmpty
            ? const Flexible(
                child: Center(
                    child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 80.0),
                child: Text(
                  'You don\'t have any budget',
                  style: kCaption,
                ),
              )))
            : Flexible(
                child: ListView.builder(
                  physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                  itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    final budget = snapshot.data![index];
                    return Dismissible(
                      key: UniqueKey(),
                      background: const Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 12.0, right: 24),
                          child: Icon(
                            IconlyLight.delete,
                            color: cRed,
                            size: 24,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      direction: DismissDirection.endToStart,
                      onDismissed: (direction) {
                        snapshot.data!.removeAt(index);
                        Provider.of<BudgetDatabaseHelper>(context,
                                listen: false)
                            .removeMethod(budget.id!, budget.budgetName);
                      },
                      child: GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () => showModalBottomSheet(
                          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                          context: context,
                          enableDrag: true,
                          isScrollControlled: true,
                          builder: (context) {
                            return DraggableScrollableSheet(
                              snap: true,
                              minChildSize: 0.43,
                              maxChildSize: 0.85,
                              initialChildSize: 0.43,
                              snapSizes: const [0.43, 0.85],
                              builder: (context, scrollController) {
                                return ClipRRect(
                                  borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                                      topLeft: Radius.circular(32),
                                      topRight: Radius.circular(32)),
                                  child: Container(
                                    color: cWhite,
                                    child: SingleChildScrollView(
                                      controller: scrollController,
                                      physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                                      child: BudgetDetails(
                                        id: budget.id!,
                                        budgetName: budget.budgetName,
                                        budgetSpent: 'budgetSpent',
                                        colorValue:
                                            colorSwatch[budget.colorValue],
                                        maxBudget: currency.format(
                                            int.parse(budget.maxBudget)),
                                        svgIcon: iconListBudgetDetails[
                                            budget.iconValue],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                );
                              },
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                        child: BudgetCard(
                            budgetName: budget.budgetName,
                            budgetSpent: '${Provider.of<SpendingDatabaseHelper>(context, listen: false).getSpecificSpending(budget.budgetName}',
                            maxBudget: currency.format(int.parse(budget.maxBudget)),
                            svgIcon: iconListBudgetCards[budget.iconValue],
                            color: colorSwatch[budget.colorValue],
                            percentage: 0.5),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              );
      },
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `provider` in a widget tree is not a good idea. Make a `statefullWidget`

Make a getter in your `SpendingDatabaseHelper` like this

```
String? _budgetSpendingAmount;

String get budgetSpendingAmount=> _budgetSpendingAmount;
```

and initialize it like this `_budgetSpendingAmount = currency.format(int.parse(c.trim()));`

So using this getter you can access this value anywhere in widget tree

```
Future<void> _getSpecificSpending(String budgetName)async{

try{
    await Provider.of<SpendingDatabaseHelper>(context, listen: false).getSpecificSpending(budgetName);
} catch(e){
     print('error :$e');
}


}
```

and in your widget tree write something like this

```
child:  FutureBuilder(
          future : _getSpecificSpending(budget.budgetName)
          builder: (ctx,snapshot){
      
var spendDataProv=Provider.of<SpendingDatabaseHelper>(context, listen: false);
             
return snapshot.connectionState==ConnectionState.waiting ?
                 CircularProgressIndicator() :
         BudgetCard(
                        budgetName: budget.budgetName,
                        budgetSpent:spendDataProv.budgetSpendingAmount ,
                        maxBudget: currency.format(int.parse(budget.maxBudget)),
                        svgIcon: iconListBudgetCards[budget.iconValue],
                        color: colorSwatch[budget.colorValue],
                        percentage: 0.5)
          },
    )
```

Comment: I've actually tried to do it that way, but the thing is the 'budget.budgetName' only can be accessed below this code ```final budget = snapshot.data![index];``` where I clarify what 'budget' means. So putting the provider code outside of the build just doesn't work,

Comment: ok , I update my answer please check

Comment: okay after a few testing, the code actually works... but only if I got just 1 budget in my database. If I have more, the spending amount of 1 budget gets reflected in all budget cards. I'm thinking maybe it's because it's assigned to the 'budgetSpendingAmount' variable. You got any idea how to get it right?

Comment: What I think you can pass this `budget.budgetName` value to  `BudgetCard` and try to retrieve this value from there  like I did here

Answer (score 0):

Some idea's

Use a FutureBuilder inside your BudgetCard widget. You can then show a CircularProgressIndicator where the spent amount is going to be when you are still waiting on the future to finish.

Or

Use a Boolean flag (which you flip at the beginning of the future method and at the end) that indicates whether the future is finished. Flag false: show progressIndicator, flag true show the spent amount.

Or

When calling `Provider.of<BudgetDatabaseHelper>(context).getBudgets()` you can let the method `getBudgets()` also fill an array with the information you need later on. So, call `Provider.of<SpendingDatabaseHelper>(context, listen: false).getSpecificSpending(budget.budgetName)` inside the `getBudgets()` method for each budgetName you have.